# How can I rewrite this code so that execution is not forced to start from Javascript Promise .then() method?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, synchronous, es6-promise

I am playing with the JS Google API library.

How can I change the following code...

```
function initializeGapiClient(){
    API_KEY = "api-key";
    API_NAME = "youtube";
    API_VERSION = "v3";

    gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);

    gapi.client.load(API_NAME, API_VERSION).then(function() { 
      alert('youtube api loaded.'); 
      // return gapi; // I know this is wrong
      // But I don't want to trigger code execution from here...
    });
}
```

so that instead of starting execution from the .then() method, I could do, whenever I want in code, something similar to:

```
var gapi = initializeGapiClient();
```

and then

```
gapi.client.youtube.search.list({ ... });
```

without getting: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'client' of undefined*

I know that I can't return from the .then() method, because it's not possible to give a variable (gapi) a valid value when assigning it to something that will be returned returned in the Future... so are there other ways **which do not involve modifying the library code**? Maybe I could turn this into a sync method? But how?

Comment: It's async, so you can't use the methods before they are loaded inside the `then` callback

Comment: @adeneo I know already. Read the whole of my question please.

Comment: I have read it, and the answer is, you can't do it that way, at least not without rewriting the entire Google API script. There's no way to force an async function to be synchronous *(well, there is, you could use a while loop that hangs the thread, but what would be the point)*.

Comment: Just return a promise from `initializeGapiClient`, that's the whole idea.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understand your question completely. But I think you have the right idea returning the api from within the promise. If you also return the `gapi.clent.load()` method outside of it, you can promise off of the entire function.

```
function initializeGapiClient(){
    API_KEY = "api-key";
    API_NAME = "youtube";
    API_VERSION = "v3";

    gapi.client.setApiKey(API_KEY);

    return gapi.client.load(API_NAME, API_VERSION).then(function(gapi) { 
      alert('youtube api loaded.');
      return gapi;
    });
}
```

If you declare a variable outside the `initializeGapiClient()` function (and its promised callbacks), you can assign the promise result to it.

```
var gapi;

initializeGapiClient().then(function(cbGapi){
  gapi = cbGapi;

  gapi.client.youtube.search.list({ ... });
});
```

Not sure why you would want to start JS execution without a promise. I think it's helpful when loading API's.

UPDATE: For error handling (when the api is not loaded yet)

```
function apiSearch(...){
  if(gapi) gapi.client.youtube.search.list({ ... });
  else console.log("Api unavailable!");
}
```

Something like that would account for errors of doing actions before the api is ready.

Comment: Thanks and welcome to SO, just that for now :) I'll explore your solution soon because it seems promising ;)

Comment: Thanks, if it doesn't work, I'd be curious to hear more about what would still be wrong.

Comment: Ok, analyzing this better now... *If you declare a variable outside the initializeGapiClient() function you can assign the promise result to it.* Yes I know but it will still be "unsafe" to use it if the callback has not returned yet, right? So the only way I could use this is by continuously checking if gapi has ben set yet at a regular time interval... right?

Comment: @jj_ - that is correct, setting the variable inside the callback like that means it's set at a later time, and doesn't really help you at all, as you'd still have to check if `gapi` is set somehow, and then you'd have to fiddle around with timers and stuff, and just using the `then` callback, like you should be doing, seems like a breeze in comparison.

Comment: Yes I know, but, let me try to explain it in a simple way.. I have a searchYouTube(query) function, now I need (for reason too long to explain here) to initialize the Google API client on each call to the searchYouTube function. I'd like my searchYouTube function to initialize the Google API client, and then, well.. search youtube ;) But I don't want to write the youtube search code inside the promise, or in another function called by the promise. I'd just want that searchYouTube could have code for that! I hope I did explain myself. I think I'm kinda fighting against the evented nature of JS.

Comment: continued: I know I could just rename initializeGapiClient() into youTubeSearch(query), and have inside of it the code for Google API initialization (running each time the method is called), and the code for the search, triggered by the promise... but at the same time I still wanted to have the Google API initialization code in its own function, at the top of the code, together with other libraries initializations that are not asynchronous, which would feel nicer to look at, and more organized ;) whew.. I did it.

Comment: @jj_ if the concern is invoking the variable before it has anything (before the promise is resolved), maybe set up your app in a way that anything that could invoke the function is disabled/unavailable, and inside the code of the promise (where we are also assigning the `gapi` variable) write code to enable the calls at that point.

Comment: @jj_ just updated the answer with a way to prevent api calls if the api is not ready.

Comment: Thanks. I think you don't need to give gapi parameter to the anonymous function in the future for the promise (hopefully I am using the right terminology... )  `gapi.client.load(API_N, API_V).then(function(gapi) { ... // otherwise here the outside gapi will be overwritten  });`. I hope it makes sense...

Answer (score 0):

You can introduce a global variable and assign the result in the then function. However you need to make sure that the value is assigned before you actually call it .

Answer (score 0):

This is a fundamental problem of asynchronous readiness whether one uses promises or not. I see a couple of alternatives, listed in increasing order of "only if you have to":

### Invariants

Make sure that code can only be called once ready. E.g.

```
let gapi;
initializeGapiClient().then(r => (gapi = r, button.disabled = false)).catch(log);

button.onclick = () => gapi.client.youtube.search.list({ ... });
```

This works with existing code, and has the advantage that any subsequent synchronous actions are still launched synchronously (which may not matter if all actions are asynchronous).

### Promise

If you can't provide said invariants, use a single promise to represent readiness, and key all code off of it.

```
let haveGapi = initializeGapiClient(); // do once

b.onclick = () => haveGapi.then(g => g.client.youtube.search.list(...)).catch(log);
```

You can reuse `haveGapi` as many times as you want; `initializeGapiClient` is still only called once. All actions are now asynchronous, due to `.then` being inherently asynchronous.

### Proxy

If you don't control the calling code, create a proxy object to hide the promises. This only works if all actions are asynchronous already.

```
function GapiProxy() {
  this.haveGapi = initializeGapiClient();
  this.list = arg => haveGapi.then(g => g.client.youtube.search.list(arg));
  this.client = { youtube: { search: { list: this.list } } };
}

let gapi = new GapiProxy();
b.onclick = () => gapi.client.youtube.search.list(...);
```